# Remote script cleaning up

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote, trap, disk-cleanup

I run a remote script using ssh:

local script:

```
local_command
ssh -p 222 user@server 'sh -s' < ./remote_run.sh
```

remote script:

```
some_command & 
sleep 10000
trap 'echo exiting' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGABRT SIGKILL EXIT
```

I need a trap on remote script for cleaning up (kill running processes and remove files).
But used approach does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe SIGHUP when `ssh` is involved?

Comment: Are you asking what to put in place of `echo exiting` to perform this cleanup?

Comment: @Barmar, No, the problem is that 'echo exiting' is never invoked.

Comment: Then @mtm is probably right, you need to add more signals to the `trap`.

Comment: Do you want the cleanup to happen when `some_command` exits? Or after 10000 seconds?

Comment: @Gilles, No, I want the cleanup when `local script` receives <Ctrl+C>

Comment: @mtm, Unforunatly adding `SIGHUP` makes no effect -- the behaviour is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and worked like charm.

```
ssh -p 222 user@server "nohup ./remote_run.sh"
```

and in remote_run.sh

```
some_command &
sleep 10000
ps -aux | grep "[r]emote_run.sh" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
#killed
```

obviously, the script is transferred to remote host first. :)